# WinSCP .NET assembly does not recognize FTP link/URL in Session.PutFiles

Tags: c#, ssis, ftp, winscp, winscp-net

Uploading some txt files from a local folder to a specific FTP address (I'm using this, `ftp://ftpint/sales/to_system/`) is one of my daily routines. I'm using ZappySys for automate this routine, but my company doesn't want to use it anymore, so i think WinSCP could be a good option.
I've installed WinSCP 5.19 & .NET assembly and followed the instructions from this link, https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_ssis. But I think WinSCP can't recognize my FTP link. Here's my C# code, any suggestions? Thank you.

```
using System;
using WinSCP;

class Example
{
    public static int Main()
    {
        try
        {
            // Setup session options
            SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
            {
                Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
                HostName = "xxx",
                UserName = "xxx",
                Password = "xxx",
                SshHostKeyFingerprint = "SHA-256 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
            };

            using (Session session = new Session())
            {
                // Connect
                session.Open(sessionOptions);

                // Upload files
                TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
                transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;

                TransferOperationResult transferResult =
                    session.PutFiles(@"C:\Users\Diomedas\test\*", "ftp://ftpint/sales/to_system/", false, transferOptions);

                // Throw on any error
                transferResult.Check();

                // Print results
                foreach (TransferEventArgs transfer in transferResult.Transfers)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Upload of {0} succeeded", transfer.FileName);
                }
            }

            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e);
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`remotePath` argument of `Session.PutFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_putfiles#remotepath) is a remote *path*. Not any URL. So it should be like:

```
session.PutFiles(@"C:\Users\Diomedas\test\*", "/sales/to_system/", false, transferOptions);
```

- You have already specified the hostname in [`SessionOptions.HostName`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions#hostname). No point trying to repeat that information.
- Your protocols do not match. You have specified `Protocol.Sftp` in [`SessionOptions.Protocol`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions#protocol), while your URL has `ftp://`. Make sure you know what is the actual protocol of your server.

---

WinSCP GUI can [generate full working code (including the upload part)](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating) for you.